# Cannot destroy tenant secret - Shield Encryption

Tags: apex, shield-encryption

I am trying to view masked characters for the encrypted fields. Since masks are disabled since Sring 17, the workaround seems to be to delete the tenant to view masked characters. I am not able to delete the tenants as I cannot see a Delete link next to the tenants.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you the admin of the org? And do you have profile permission to perform this action? Please check the profile permissions once.

Comment: @NitishSinghal, I am the admin and I do have 'Manage Encryption keys' permission. I could generte a tenanat and cannot figure out how to delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can not destroy the active key, you can only destroy an archived key. Could you please try to rotate it first, then you should be able to destroy it and see the data encrypted with that key showing as "????".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am trying these things out on my personal org, so the reply is delayed as I get to work on it on weekends. I am not able to generate a new tenant in my dev org. The current key is shown as ACTIVE. Is it a limitation with dev orgs?